# EntityFramework custom many to many without navigation property

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want to do many-to-many relation between these objects:

```
class Flyer { 
     Guid Id; 
     virtual ICollection<Address> Stores; 
}
```

And:

```
class Address {
     Guid Id;
 }
```

Of course these models are simplified.

And I do not want a navigation property to `Flyer` inside `Address` because `Address` is in relation with other objects too. It is possible?

**Fluent API only**

Comment: "I do not want a navigation property to ..." - then you don't  want a Relation there, and the many-to-many becomes irrelevant/undefined. What do you mean with that anyway?

Comment: `And I do not want a navigation property to Flyer inside Address because Address is in relation with other objects too.` If every linked table is a separate FK column in the DB, you can put a navigational property for each connected type. If you are using a single column to enter an FK that could reference one of several tables, then you are working beyond the scope of what EF provides and will need to add custom logic to translate your FK (which will still need to be a property in your `Address`) to a `Flyer` or any other connected type. For the latter option: what have you tried??

Answer (score 0):

How are you identifying what the address belongs to if it can belong to multiple different tables? Do you have a Join table? Like a AddressToFlyer Table that establishes the relationship between the two tables?

When I have complex queries that need to take place like this where one table can be used by many tables, I create join tables and typically create views that handle the joins and give me the data what I want so I can just do a select in Entity Framework and not worry about the Navigational property, then implement said view in Entity framework like you would a regular table.